# Using ajax.start with multiple calls

Tags: ajax

I am using ajaxStart function to show a message while it's in process. The only thing is I have more than one ajax call so the message keeps firing. Is there a way to give the function a name or something so it only listens to the one call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `beforeSend` instead, you set it for only the ajax request you want the message to show for, you can even use the `complete` at the end of the request.

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: () => showMessageOrSomething(),
  complete: () => hideMsgMaybeIdk()
})
```

If you insist on going the `ajaxStart` route you can set the `global` parameter to false in the ajax calls you do not want the function to execute.

```
$.ajax({
  global: false,
  url: 'no/popup/please'
})
```